# Should there be separate power isolators for CAN and PWM if the PWM driven system is high voltage and noisy?

Tags: isolated, digital-isolator

[image]

In this system, suppose the high voltage system does not have isolated ground references. The mcu CAN rx,tx signals and the PWM signal for the HV motor controller are isolated with digital isolators, and all ground planes are connected through Y capacitors. Are there any possible issues if I power both digital isolators from the same isolated power supply? Would having two separate power isolators be a better approach in terms of noise suppression and safety?